# Trouble with CKEditor when displaying output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor along with `ASP.NET MVC`, but there's a very strange problem : if I format some text (e.g. apply boldness, make it italic, or make a list) when there's some error and the content must be post back to the textarea, it is displayed as HTML text - "ul  li " and so on instead of being styled again (bold, italic and so on).

I've applied some options in the config:

```
config.htmlEncodeOutput = true; // to avoid text being interpreted as attack

config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR; // in order not to place tags arround the text 

config.basicEntities = false; // do display spaces as they are instead of &nbsp; and so on...
```

I tried some built in functions in `MVC` like `Server.HtmlDecode` and `HttpUtility.Decode` but nothing seems to work. Solutions with other editors which will work fine with `MVC` are also accepted.

Here is the .cshmtl file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CkEditor";
}

@model HtmlTextEditorsDemos.Models.SimpleModel

<h2>CkEditor</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text, new { @class = "ckeditor" })
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
}
```

In the action method I do nothing but to return the data again just for testing purposes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SimpleModel model)
{
    //model.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(model.Text);
    return View(model);
}
```

The SimpleModel class is just a test model class with only 1 property - Text.

Comment: Please include the code of how you are populating that text area. Most likely you'll need something like `Html.Raw`.

Comment: Yes, Html.Raw will do the work (but only if it was to be displayed in a div or paragraph or other element like these), but the problem is that the value in the textarea can't be IHtmlString, it can be only string value. I tried Html.Raw(Model.Text).ToHtmlString() but in vain.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you manage to find a fix for it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
           @{
    string description = Server.HtmlDecode(item.Description);
           }
            @Html.Raw(description)

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="~/img/Uploads/@item.Pic" width="150" height="120" />
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```